# Using regex to find elements based on partial contents of attributes

Tags: jquery, regex

How do I go about using regex to match any anchor whos href starts with "#t_row_" ?
For example, one of the anchors looks like: `<a href="#t_row_234567890">Link</a>`

Currently I have:

```
$('a[href*=#]')each(function() {
```

Cheers

Comment: did you forget the `.` before each()?

Answer (score 2):

For this exact case, use the [jQuery Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('a[href^="#t_row"]')
```

Alternatively, in a more general case, you can [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) any set of elements based on arbitrary JS code. In this case it would be:

```
$('a').filter(function(i){ return /^#t_row/.test(this.href); });
```

Comment: As @FelixKing suggested before he pulled his answer, I too recommend that you have a look at [all available selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a regex. `$('a[href^="#t_row_"]')` will do the job.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
$('a[href^="#t_row_"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/